# Visual studio extension: Change editor tab name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I try to change the caption of an editor tab in Visual Studio 2017 with an extension. 
Coming from DTE2 and using the getter ActiveWindow I can read the caption, but if I change it a "System.InvalidOperationException" exception occurs.

```cs
var dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
var currentWindows = dte.Windows;

foreach (Window window in dte.Windows)
{
    if (window.Caption.EndsWith("cs"))
        window.Caption = "foo";            
}
```

Implementing the IWpfTextViewCreationListener I can get the created IWpfTextView of an opened File, but I cannot find the caption there.

```cs
internal sealed class ViewportAdornment1TextViewCreationListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{  
    public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
    {
        // Own implementation
        new ViewportAdornment1(textView);
    }
}
```

Can any give me a starting point, where I can proceed?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us a [mcve] of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Adding code examples done  :D

Comment: It seems that I have to override the CreateDocumentWindow method

Comment: @kali, Do you resolve it in your side?

Comment: Sry for the late response. No I did not. I switched to another project :D